# Is "I wish I had one of those ..." correctly used in the following sentence?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, wish-preterite

> Sex Education Club? **I wish I had one of those** when I was a student.

The **bolded** part actually means, *I wish my university had had one of those so I could have joined . . .*

But I picked *I wish I had one of those . . .* because it's shorter.

So my question is, would a native English speaker use that phrase in that manner (as an expression or idiom)? If not, what would be a better alternative?

Comment: Perfectly idiomatic as it stands.  About the only change I'd make is add "Gee" -- "Gee, I wish..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite correct. You need:

*I wish I **had had** **access** to one of those when I **was** a student.*

or:

*I wish **there had been** one of those **around** when I **was** a student.*

E.g.

> [Restoration](https://books.google.ca/books?id=juWMJSlYChUC&pg=PA200&dq=%22wish%20I%20had%20had%22%20%22when%20I%20was%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=i8c9VYWlJfX_sASd4YD4BQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22wish%20I%20had%20had%22%20%22when%20I%20was%22&f=false) - Page 200 George F. Will - 2010
>
> I have to pay taxes, meet a payroll — I wish I **had had** a better
>   sense of what it took to do that when I **was** in Washington.

Comment: Or  "I wish _they_ had one of those..,"  This is an impersonal, vague "they"  such as in  "They don't make 'em like they used to."

Answer (score 1):

That can not be an idiom at any cost. I wish I had one of those is ....(this usage is fine nothing wrong in that)